# Modifying the BNF grammar to allow new binary operation

Tags: bnf

I am going through the concept BNF. I got to know how to draw the syntax trees and finding the ambiguous grammar. I came to know that the grammar can be modified and the new binary operation(&) an be added to the existing grammar with implied precedence. I have searched alot to find how to do that but I am left with no clue.. I have the following grammar

```
E::= E+T|T
T::= T*F|F
F::='('E')'|a|b|c
```

Can anyone give me some insight on this

Comment: What precedence do you want `&` to have?  How would you parenthesize `a&b*c`?  How would you parenthesize `a+b&c`?

Comment: I want the & to have precedence between that of * and +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
E::= E+A|A
A::= A&T|T
T::= T*F|F
F::='('E')'|a|b|c
```

Comment: Here is what I understood: So when the non-terminal starts with E::=E+A and before it reaches the T*F it has to pass through the statement A&T.. so which means that & precedence is between * and +. Am I correct at this point? please correct me if not

Comment: @DeepakMudiam: I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.  The precedence of operators is an emergent effect of the expansion of E->A->T->F with higher precedence operators being associated with non-terminals later in the chain, which makes them closer to the leaves in the parse tree.